# Invoking JS Interop Function for DOM element located in submenu in Blazor

Tags: javascript, html, .net, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I am trying to invoke a JS function that creates a modal on user click through JS Interop in Blazor. The thing is, the function is using a onclick event for a DOM element that is inside a Blazor submenu. When that DOM Element is outside the submenu in the side navbar, it works fine. When I put that element inside the submenu, Blazor complains that it `cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

Here is my navbar HTML and JS Interop code

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
                <span class="oi oi-fork" aria-hidden="true"></span> AccountPage
            </NavLink>
            @if (expandSubNav)
            {
        <ul  class="nav flex-column" id="submenu">
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <a class="expand-menu" href="page">
                    <span>element1</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <a class="expand-menu" href="page">
                    <span>element2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <a class="expand-menu" href="page">
                    <span>element3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <a class="expand-menu">
                   
                    <div   id="addBtn" ><span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Element</div>
                    </a>
            </li>
      


        </ul>
            }
        </li>
       
        

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h1 class="modal-title">
            <b>Add Element Here</b>
        </h1>

        <input id="addelementtext" type="text" />
        <button id="add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-defaultcloseissue" id="closebtn" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="">Close</button>



    </div>
</div>





    </div>
</div>
@code { private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private bool expandSubNav;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {


        if (firstRender)
        {
            
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("createModal");
            
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to use onclick with this id element

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
                <a class="expand-menu">
                   
                    <div   id="addBtn" ><span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Element</div>
                    </a>
            </li>
```

It is inside the submenu it created. When I put it outside the submenu into the main nav menu, the JS function does not complain and it works fine.

I have also tried doing this

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {


        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (expandSubNav)
            {
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("createModal");

            }
        }
    }
```

This stops the error but clicking the element does nothing. How can I go about fixing this? I am trying to research about the Blazor LifeCycle as I feel this is a rendering issue but I am having a hard time understanding what I can do.

Here is also the JS function that I am trying to call

```
window.createModal = function createModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    var closebtn = document.getElementById("closebtn");


    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }



    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    closebtn.onclick = function (event) {

        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error, `cannot set property 'onclick' of null`, happens because the subnav portion is not expanded when the navbar is first rendered, so the `addBtn` element isn't found in the DOM yet when you call `var btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");`

The second issue is because your `if()` statement only runs once, on first render, while `expandSubnav` is false. So your `await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("createModal");` line will never get executed.

If you notice in the `@code` block there's a method for toggling the `collapseNavMenu`:

```
private void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
}
```

If you did something similar, but for `expandSubnav`, you could use that as an opportunity to hook in your `createModal` code. You only want to do it once, so you'd probably want to keep track of that too. Something like:

```
private bool modalCreated = false;
private void ToggleSubNav()
{
    expandSubnav = !expandSubnav;
    if(!modalCreated)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("createModal");
        modalCreated = true;
    }
}
```

And then hook that into your NavLink:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="ToggleSubNav">
    <span class="oi oi-fork" aria-hidden="true"></span> AccountPage
</NavLink>
```